# Сгенерировать obj-файлы компилятором Go

Tags: windows, golang, ассемблер, fasm

У меня немного необычная задача. Надо слинковать объектные файлы, созданные компилятором FASM, с `.o`-файлами, которые делает команда `go tools compile` из сорцов. Но формат .o-файла не подходит для линковки с obj-файлами. Как создать obj-файлы компилятором го?

```asm
format COFF
use32

MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN   equ 1 shl 0
MBOOT_MEM_INFO     equ 1 shl 1
MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS equ (MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN) or (MBOOT_MEM_INFO)
MBOOT_CHECKSUM     equ -(MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)

mboot:
  dd MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
  dd MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
  dd MBOOT_CHECKSUM
  dd mboot

extrn go.kernel.Load

start:
  push ebx
  cli
  call go.kernel.Load
  hlt
```

Сорец на го компилирую командой `go tools compile kernel.go`

```golang
package kernel

func Load() {

}
```

Линкую так:

```sh
$ C:\Asm\kernel>C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe -T link.ld kernel.o multiboot.obj -o kernel.img
kernel.o: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
$ C:\Asm\kernel>pause
```

Скрипт линкера:

```
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{

    .text 0x100000 :
    {
        code = .; _code = .; __code = .;
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .data :
    {
        data = .; _data = .; __data = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .bss :
    {
        bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    end = .; _end = .; __end = .;
}
```

Comment: Что значит «не подходит»? Пишите, какие сорцы есть сейчас, и какими командами пользуетесь.

Comment: @Ainar-G, обновил пост

Comment: Пока непонятно. На «Linux» есть «-buildmode c-archive», который должен собирать си-совместимый архивный файл, но заставить его работать с «fasm» пока не удалось.

Comment: @Ainar-G, я компилирую под виндой

Comment: Как вариант, можно поменять ассемблерную часть, чтобы компилировалось в elf формат (или какой там формат у .o файла)